# How does one global snap to grid with ProBuilder?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-probuilder

Seriously, the grid snapping in ProBuilder is driving me crazy. For some reasons it's so inconsistent, sometimes the snapping works, but most of the time it's completely misaligned. And that's with shapes created with the grid snapping enabled, on 0.25.

Video showcase:
https://streamable.com/njmv5p

[image]
[image]
[image]